# Will_paginate Click on page link does not show anything

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

My tab content just show blank page when i click on the pagination links. I do not understand why. Please help me with it. My images will load when i first load the page, but nothing appears when i click on page 2 on the pagination button.

My View Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
            localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
        });
        var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
        if(activeTab){
            $('#TabLength a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
        }
    });
</script>
<div>
<div id="TabBlock">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="TabLength">
    <% @biscuit.each_index do |i| %>
      <% if i == 0 %>
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#<%= @biscuit[i] %>"><%= @biscuit[i] %></a></li>
      <% else %>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#<%= @biscuit[i] %>"><%= @biscuit[i] %></a></li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <%= render "products" %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My Partial Products Code

```
<% @biscuit.each_index do |i| %>
    <% if i == 0 %>
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="<%= @biscuit[i] %>">
        <div class="row" id="PictureSetting">
        <% @title = @biscuit[i].camelize.constantize %>
        <% @testpage = @title.paginate(:page => params[@biscuit[i]], :per_page => 9) %>
            <% @testpage.each do |i| %>
              <div class="col-md-4" id="ProductPic">
                <%= image_tag(i.name , class:"img-thumbnail", size:"180x180") %>
              </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <%= will_paginate @testpage, :param_name => @biscuit[i] %>
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="<%= @biscuit[i] %>">
        <div class="row" id="PictureSetting">
        <% @title = @biscuit[i].camelize.constantize %>
        <% @testpage = @title.paginate(:page => params[@biscuit[i]], :per_page => 9) %>
           <% @testpage.each do |i| %>
              <div class="col-md-4" id="ProductPic">
                <h1>Hello</h1>
              </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>  
        <%= will_paginate @testpage, :param_name => @biscuit[i] %>
        </div>  
      </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My Controller Code

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

BiscuitCategory = Array.new

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

end

def new
end 

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def cashier
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @biscuit = category_store
end

def category_store
  BiscuitCategory.clear
  totalnum = Biscuit.count("BiscuitType")
  counter = 1
  while counter <= totalnum
    BiscuitCategory.push(Biscuit.find(counter).BiscuitType)
    counter+=1
  end 
  return BiscuitCategory
end
```

My Route Code

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'webpage#login'
  get 'login' => 'webpage#login'
  post 'login' => 'webpage#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'webpage#destroy'
  resources :users do
    member do
      get 'cashier'
    end
  end
```

Comment: I recommend using kaminari, it is much easier than will_paginate.

Comment: What URL is rendered into the link? How are your routes defined? Which action is processed when you click the link? Is a request made at all? Your question is like : 'Help, my car does not drive! Here is the type of tires I use:..'

Comment: Can you post your controller code

Comment: @axelTetzlaff The URL that got render when i click on the page 2 pagination button, http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/1/cashier?Chocolate=2. I am suspecting it has something to do with bootstrap.js. Because the page starts to go blank when i include bootstrap.js inside my /assets/javascripts

Comment: cleve yeo, how did you solve this problem? I'm facing something similar at the moment.